# Kivy: How do I move from one canvas/screen to another?

Tags: python, kivy

Supposedly, I have this.

```
class MainGui(App):
    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        login_button = Button(text="Let's go")
        login_button.bind(on_press = self.login)
        login_button_area.add_widget(login_button)
        root.add_widget(login_button_area)

    def login(self, instance):
        pass
```

Now when login_button is clicked I want to change the whole layout to a new one. How do I do that?

I tried this

```
def login(self, instance):
    root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world', multiline=False)
    textinput.bind(on_text_validate=self.on_enter)
    root.add_widget(textinput)

    return root
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `kivy.uix.screenmanager`. Second example from [documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html) (one with Menu Screen and a Settings Screen) should be useful.